# Jsoup with a plugin

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to scrape some online data from different stores, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to programmatically replicate what I do as a user. To get the data manually (after logging in), a user must select a store from [a tree](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2135055/Tree.png) that pops up.

As best I can tell, the tree is not hard-coded into the site but is built interactively when your computer interacts with the server. When you look for the table in "view page source," there are no entries. When I [inspect the tree](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2135055/TreeInspect.png), I do see the HTML and it seems to come from the "FancyTree" plugin.

As best as I can tell from tracking my activity on Developer Tools -- Network, the next step is a "GET" request which doesn't change the URL, so I'm not sure how my store selection is being transferred.

Any advice on how to get Jsoup or Java generally to programmatically interact with this table would be extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: DOMS are too dynamic these days to hope to parse just html and get anything useful. You'll need to use a tool like Selenium which remote controls browsers. That way you can ask it to find the buttons and drop downs, select the right elements, have the JS executed correctly and then ask the browser for the DOMS current state when everything is correct. Then you can parse that with jsoup. If this is a server side application using Linux, you can still do everything headless using xvfb (helpful hint if that is the case).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd give it an upvote if I could upvote comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup can only parse the original source file, not the DOM.  In order to parse the DOM, you'll need to render the page with something like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).  Then you can parse the html content with Jsoup.

```
// load page using HTML Unit and fire scripts
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage(myURL);

// convert page to generated HTML and convert to document
doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());

// do something with html content
System.out.println(doc.html());

// clean up resources        
webClient.close();
```

See [Parsing Javascript Generated Page with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368045/jsoup-fetching-a-partial-page/38734066#38734066).