# Can't scrape the data that i'm looking for?

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I am trying to scrape the prices and the dates in the table in the attached picture from the URL: **** 
[http://www.airfrance.fr/vols/paris+tunis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FhZ.png)

I succeeded to scrape informations but not the ways i'm looking for ( date + price). I used these lines of code

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.airfrance.fr/vols/paris+tunis").get();
            Elements links = doc.select("div");
            for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element e:links) {
                System.out.println(e.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code gives me just some prices and anly a few dates but not all the table as it shown in the picture below.

[image]

Can you help me please to resolve this problem for my study project and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the calendar you are parsing is not in the original source code (right click > view source) as delivered from the server.  That table is generated using JavaScript when the page is rendered by the browser (right click > inspect).

Jsoup can only parse source code.  So you need to load the page first with something like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), then pass this rendered paged to Jsoup.

```
// load page using HTML Unit and fire scripts
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage("http://www.airfrance.fr/vols/paris+tunis");

// convert page to generated HTML and convert to document
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());

// find all of the date/price cells
for(Element cell : doc.select("td.available.daySelection")) {
    String cellDate = cell.select(".cellDate").text();
    String cellPrice = cell.select(".cellPrice > .day_price").text();
    System.out.println(
            String.format(
                    "cellDate=%s cellPrice=%s", 
                    cellDate, 
                    cellPrice));
}

// clean up resources        
webClient.close();
```

Console

```
cellDate=1 septembre cellPrice=302 €
cellDate=2 septembre cellPrice=270 €
cellDate=3 septembre cellPrice=270 €
cellDate=4 septembre cellPrice=270 €
cellDate=5 septembre cellPrice=270 €
....
```

Source: [Parsing JavaScript Generated Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368045/jsoup-fetching-a-partial-page/38734066#38734066)

Comment: Thanks, you really get the problem but i still have a problem with webClient.close() when i tried your code.

Comment: Can't posted here !!! the sad it's too long. i sent you a facebook request or if you don't mind pass me your mail and i will be grateful .

Comment: Open a new question and be specific about the issue you are having with WebClient.close().  You should post only the relevant blocks of your code, not the entire source code.

Comment: I am just missing a lot of dependencies. Have you added a specific package ?

Comment: See the link in the answer for Html Unit.

Comment: I just have Html Unit and Jsoup in my pom.

Comment: How can i do the same for this url http://www.lufthansa.com/vol/vol-paris-berlin . In this one the calendar is not shown until you click on the month and there is no changement in the url ?

Comment: Open a new question for this.

Comment: Done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939782/how-to-parse-a-hidden-javascript-section-from-a-html-page