# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver

Tags: java, htmlunit

Reference:

https://devpal.co/blog/web-scraping-with-java-and-htmlunit/

I am doing exactly same steps as mentioned in the blog but getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate declared field class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver
```

for the below call

```java
HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage("https://devpal.co");
```

pom.xml entry

https://gist.github.com/vikramvi/05073952de1a0b18c1863d80ef93b75a

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.70.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have a different version of the Apache Httpclient in your classpath.

I think there are two possible reasons:

- another lib in your project requires an older version and therefor maven chooses this one
- you are on android (there is an old version build in in the android jre). If you are on android please use HtmlUnit Android package instead (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android)

Comment: Can you please clarify how did you find out that "you have a different version of the Apache Httpclient in your classpath.", I've added complete pom.xml in the question, can you please check and clarify what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I did                             System.out.println(HttpClientBuilder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
and it's pointing to "file:/Users/vikramanna/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar", how can I make it to point to correct version of httpclient ?

Comment: References : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20137/htmlunit-driver-error, https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1786/

Comment: "how did you find out" - that's more or less what the error msg says - at compile time there was a field HttpClientBuilder.dnsResolver but this field is not available at runtime. The usual reason for that is that you have a different version of the class in your classpath.

Comment: "..you have a different version of the class in your classpath.." how can I fix this ?