# How does Apache HttpClient is related to htmlunit?

Tags: httpclient, htmlunit

I'm having below entry in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.70.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but it's pointing to quite older version of httpclient

```
file:/Users/User_Name/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar
```

Do I need to explicitly mention httpclient version as well in pom.xml ?

What's the relationship between these two ?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit uses the Apache HttpClient to do all the Http releated work.
The current version (2.70.0) uses the 4.5.x version of the HttpClient. HttpClient 5.x has a different API - therefore it is not possible to use the 5.x version.
Some work was already done to migrate to 5.x but this in alpha stage at the moment.

There is no need to mention the httpclient version in your pom - usually maven does the management of the dependencies for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I had asked this query to understand more about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75565026/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-locate-declared-field-class-org-apach. But per above answer; it should have picked up latest version of HttpClient but it's not happening in my case.